# Valores em determinados ID's estão visíveis no banco mas não estão visíveis no destinatário

Tags: sql

Estou tentando inserir uma lista de dados, porém, em determinado período alguns ID's não estão sendo enviados ao destinatário. Consigo verificar no sql que os valores inseridos existem, mas não estão visíveis (ou não existem) para o meu destino. Ou seja, estão visíveis no banco, mas no destino do qual era para aparecer os valores não estão aparecendo, outros id's estão aparecendo normal.

obs.: A query está correta, pois outros valores estão aparecendo

```
update [dbo].[TInventerData201903] set Pac= '17529' ,EDay = '61.5' where ID = '52E38690-27A8-4CD4-9DFB-53BE896C224F';

update [dbo].[TInventerData201903] set Pac= '15198' ,EDay = '64.1' where ID = 'B81E1AE3-BAA5-452F-B275-08DCDA791216';

update [dbo].[TInventerData201903] set Pac= '5550' ,EDay = '65.0' where ID = 'B1687CE9-FB48-4C9F-BC2B-C9A5BD59A411';
```

Os primeiros updates estão visíveis no banco e no destino, porém o ultimo não ('5550'), está visível apenas no banco e não no destinatário. As querys são para um gráfico e esse id é importante para que o dado seja implementado no gráfico.

Comment: Qual é o banco de dados? SQL Server?

Comment: Sim, SQL Server Management Studio 2008